# Develop tabbed Content using HTML

Tags: tabs

I am trying to develop a tabbed system to represent my data. I am seeing that many approaches use  format for the tabs to directly navigate to the content of that tab. Is this the one and only way to develop tabbed contents? My problem is

here is the fiddle
**jsfiddle.net/rQTpB/4**

I need to include this tabs a part of a larger home page. if I develop the tabs using the above approach, when I click on any of the tabs,the page snaps to the starting of the div. I don't want that to happen. I need the tabbed functionality without that snap issue. Is there any other way to achieve my requirement?

So , far couldn't find any..:(

Thanks,

Comment: Have included the fiddle URL...if you need more info let me know..I am also including the URL of the minimal set up for tabs..http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/index.html

Comment: You're trying to prevent the page from moving to, say, #three, right? Add `return false` to the end of the click handler.

Comment: I am not clear what you meant. I am a layman using JQuery. I downloaded this script from a web site called CSS tricks. I am able to understand the script. But where exactly you want me to add ? can you edit the fiddle or post the script here for me?

Comment: Yeah got that worked..Thanks a lot..for your help...You saved much of my time today...Thanks once more...

Answer (score 0):

This is very nice work. But you could use some ready solutions for tabs. E.g. jquery ui:

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

or - based on the above, but more functions avaliable:

http://www.primefaces.org/primeui/tabview.html